# Error initializing Cordova:JSON Error

Tags: cordova

I am getting **Error Initializing Cordova:JSON Error** when i try to launch my phonegap app in Android Simulator.
I have followed this [link](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html) to setup the environment for Phonegap.I am using Cordova-2.4.0 with my own set of HTML, CSS and JS files with jQuery.The app is running when only the HTML, CSS, JS files, without PhoneGap changes are hosted in a web server.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What says the adb logcat?

Comment: Error initializing Network Connection: JSON error at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.4.0.js:6044

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the order in which the `deviceready`function/js is called. After the `deviceReady` method all the other js files are loaded.
This solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to set up the [Domain-Whitelist](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html). I would suggest to use the offical cordov tutorial at: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.4.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android to setup your project.

The link to your tutorial is for version 1.5. There was no domainwhitelisting in that version.

Comment: This is also not the issue as my config.xml has the following entries for *access-origin* 
    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> 
    <access origin=".*"/>

Comment: Not sure those domains are in the correct format. Try <access origin="*" />.