# SAP Fiori client Error initializing Cordova JSON error

Tags: javascript, cordova, sapui5, sap-fiori

I've developped a SAPUI5 app using a barcode scanner using the following code :

```html
<ndc:BarcodeScannerButton scanSuccess="handleBarcodeScannerSuccess" />
```

Once I launch the SAP Fiori client app I get an "Error initializing Cordova JSON error".
Consequence : the scanner is not recognize.

How can I bypass this message and make work the Scanner ?

EDIT : the error appears when the sap fiori client is redirected to the SSO page.

PS: Weird thing it works on my iPhone.

Comment: Here [Error initializing Cordova:JSON Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075646/error-initializing-cordovajson-error)
the problem was solved by loading the “deviceReady” method first.
Does this solve your problem as well?
What says the adb logcat?

Comment: I'm not building an Android app. I just created a Fiori app that has been deployed on Sap Fiori launchpad and normally it is the fiori client that should take care of Cordova, should'nt it ?

Comment: Just for clarification:
Your UI5 app works on your iPhone using a browser?
The FLP also works on your iPhone using a browser?

When you launch the Fiori Client with FLP you get the cordova error message?
Have you tested Fiori Client with other UI5 apps?

Comment: No my UI5 app work through the SAP Fiori Client. It is before arriving on the FLP that I have to go through the SSO page and here appears the message. Once I log in, I'm able to go through my FLP adn click on my app.

Comment: Again just for clarification, because you mentioned it works on iPhone:
If you run your Fiori Client on iPhone, FLP and UI5 app work?
On which platform do you get the error? Windows Desktop?

Comment: Yes on differents iPhones it works through the sap fiori client. I get the error only on android devices (tested different devices).

Comment: Here is my adb logcat https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0xZBNFXNK_tbDRWeG9oRXV1OGc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please check if the problem still exists after disabling nobridge. To do so, add an extra parameter to the URL used to configure the Fiori Client. For example `https://www.sapfioritrial.com/sap/hana/uis/clients/ushell-app/shells/fiori/FioriLaunchpad.html?noBridgewhitelist=*` https://www.sapfioritrial.com/sap/hana/uis/clients/ushell-app/shells/fiori/FioriLaunchpad.html?noBridgewhitelist=* Here is more [information on this topic](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/11/10/sap-fiori-client-sp13/#security).

Comment: No sucess either :o. It seems to be the right solution though

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to make Cordova work. Not the way I wanted but it works.

I copied pasted cordova in my Fiori app and the files :
- BarcodeScannerProxy.js
- cordova_plugins.js
- llqrcode.js
- qrcode.min.js
- quagga.min.js
- barcodescanner.js

And then I Launched the barcode scan with :
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan();